# How to use ASP.NET to get data from MSSQL for JQuery Autocomplete widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

I downloaded jquery-ui to use autocomplete widget and I want to get items from an MSSQL database. But I couldn't figure out how to use it in ASP.NET with sql. Codes are basically like below.

```
        var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",
            "Erlang",
            "Fortran",
            "Groovy",
            "Haskell",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lisp",
            "Perl",
            "PHP",
            "Python",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Scheme"
        ];
        $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
```

```html
 <div>
        <input id="autocomplete" title="type &quot;a&quot;">
    </div>
```

EDIT: Just find out how to do it. Just copied the jquery to the server side with below code:

```
StringBuilder strScript = new StringBuilder();
        strScript.Append("var availableTags = ['java','javascript'];");
        strScript.Append("$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({");
        strScript.Append("source: availableTags});");
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Script",
        strScript.ToString(), true);
```

Comment: Do you use MVC or Web Forms?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to write back-end side of code to get data from SQL. Then you will call this function with JQuery and you need to set this values into autocomplete source.

So your autocomplete code should look like this.

```
$("#YourAutoCompleteInputId").autocomplete({
    autoFocus: true, 
    delay: 0,
    scrollIntoView: false,
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.get("/YourControllerName/YourControllerMethod/", { searchTerm: request.term }, function (data) {
            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                return {
                    label: item.Name 
                    val: item.Id
                }
            }));
        }).fail(function () {
            alert("error");
        });
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        // whatever you return from your back-end code. you can reach here
        // you can reach it by using ui.item.label => it's your label and ui.item.val => is your value. 
        // do something when user select one the result from autocomplete list.
    },
    open: function () {
        // do something when user open autocomplete list
    },
    close: function () {
        // do something when user close autocomplete list
    }
});
```

And your method should be like this.

```
public async Task<JsonResult> GetApplicantNamesForAutoComplete(string searchTerm)
{
    var list = yourData.Where(x => x.yourTableColumnName.Contains(searchTerm))
        .Select(x => new { x.Id, Name = (x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName)});
    return Json(await list.ToListAsync(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```